# django admin cannot upload files with utf-8 filenames

Tags: django, django-admin

Updates: Thanks for Udi's recommendation, i turned on debug and updated the error message plus my model

Here is my model:

```
class booktitle(models.Model):
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book_title_zh = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    book_desc_zh = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    author_zh = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    publisher_zh = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(category)
    cover_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='books/book_img_cover', blank=True, null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date_added',)
        verbose_name = 'Book : 書本'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Book : 書本'
```

I have a standard django installation. When i use it to upload filename with Chinese Characters, it shows the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError at
>   /admin/booksfair/booktitle/6/ 'ascii'
>   codec can't encode characters in
>   position 51-53: ordinal not in
>   range(128) Request Method:    POST
>   Request
>   URL:  http://www.mydomain.com/admin/booksfair/booktitle/6/
>   Django Version:   1.4 pre-alpha
>   SVN-16395 Exception
>   Type: UnicodeEncodeError Exception
>   Value:     'ascii' codec can't encode
>   characters in position 51-53: ordinal
>   not in range(128) Exception
>   Location: /usr/lib/python2.6/genericpath.py
>   in exists, line 18 Python
>   Executable:   /usr/bin/python Python
>   Version:  2.6.7 Python Path:
>   ['/usr/lib/python26.zip', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.6', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info',
>   '/var/www', 
>   '/var/www/html/django/website', 
>   '/var/www/html/django']

I have found some resolution here, but it doesn't work for my case, this is not a duplicated post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your error messages are not useful because of incorrect settings.

- While debugging your code (on a development server), try using `DEBUG=True` and check the error messages.
- On a production server, you should [add a 500.html page to your templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view).  Following this, you might receive better error messages in your log files.  See also: https://github.com/dcramer/django-sentry

(Since you should get a very different error message,  please post your problem with the new error message again in a new question instead of updating this one.  Thanks.)